# Incorrect type inference while pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

In the following ADT, why is `Foo` incorrectly inferred for it's type parameter `S`?

```scala
sealed trait Sum[-S, +A]

case class Foo[S]() extends Sum[S, S]

def execute[S, A](mqtt: Sum[S, A], s: S): A =
  mqtt match {
    // S and A should be the same for Foo
    case Foo() => s // should compile but returns an error.
  }
```

Link on scastie https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xD4RqwKYRW20dy4K0GHEDg
[image]

Comment: @jwvh I added the error screenshot.

Comment: @DmytroMitin yes in my domain `S` is accepted and `A` is returned in some other case clases.

Comment: @DmytroMitin There was a typo, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using a typed pattern match instead of a constructor pattern match

```
sealed trait Sum[-S, +A]

case class Foo[S]() extends Sum[S, S]

def execute[S, A](mqtt: Sum[S, A], s: S): A =
  mqtt match {
      case m : Foo[S] => s
  }
```

Comment: Note that pattern matching occurs at runtime and that type parameters at erased when compiling. Depending on what you are doing, you may end up with some unexpected behavior in more complex scenarios.

Comment: @stefanobaghino Yes, but type inference inside patterns occurs at compile time anyway. And type erasure occurs at compile time at `erasure` phase, which occurs long after `typer` phase where types are inferred. I'm not arguing, just mentioning that this is not the whole story.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling method `execute` with two different type parameters `S` and `A` and compiler has no evidence they are same.

So when you try to return object of type `S` when method signature requires `A` you get an error. This has nothing to do with ADT.

You can make it work if you give compiler some more details about type parameters.
Such as this `def execute[A, S<:A]`

Comment: While pattern matching on the case class `Foo` the compiler should be able to infer that `Sum[S, A]` is actually `Sum[S, S]` and thus `Foo[S]` ?

Comment: @tusharmath Compiler can't infer that because you can call `execute[Int, String](???, 1)`.

Comment: @tusharmath Or `execute[Int, String](null, 1)` or `execute[Int, String](new Sum[Int, String] {} , 1)`